# Book trilogy about a mage transported 500 years into the past

Tags: story-identification, books, time-travel, sword-and-sorcery

Trilogy of books, about a mage who is transported 500 years into the past. He created the house he is a part of in the future.  There is a battle with a golden dragon at the end.  Cannot find the author or the series.

Comment: This is very terse. Have a look at the checklists here and add in some more detail; https://scifi.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/9335/how-to-ask-a-good-story-id-question